# Horizontal Camera with Overlay

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, orientation

I need to have a horizontal video camera input with image overlays (that are not recorded).

The problem is that, when active, the camera view is rotated 90 degrees even though everything else is correctly oriented horizontally.

UIImagePicker cannot do horizontal orientation, and I've had trouble using AVCapture with graphic overlays. So, I use a custom view and rotate that.

Camera Init

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
 {
    //Custom View Instead of UIImagePicker
    _video_picker = [[VCImagePickerController alloc] init];

    _video_picker.delegate = self;
    _video_picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    _video_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    _video_picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    _video_picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    _video_picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

    //Set the orientation
    _video_picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    //Display overlay graphics
    _video_picker.cameraOverlayView = _overVW ;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:_video_picker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then in the custom VCImagePickerController view, the mask is set:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;  
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

When the camera is in horizontal mode, it is like the rendered view is out of sync. The mask appears, but the actual camera view is incorrect. When I move the camera to the right, it goes down, as if the orientation is rotated.
Using an iPhone 6 with iOS 9.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps anyone, to make a horizontal UIImagePicker , you must create an entirely custom view.